# When I download a Rails open source project, how can I know which version of Rails or gems is needed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I download an open source Rails project, how can I know  which version of Rails or gems is needed?

For example, I want to build a blog. Then I do this:

```
~$ git clone git://github.com/mojombo/jekyll.git
```

That is a free open blog project. When the clone is 100% done.

```
~$ cd jekyll
~$ rake db:create

rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:create'
```

So what's wrong in my Rails or Gem or any other? Is there a problem of version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian and Nate have said, read the documentation about it.

I personally have a [Jekyll-powered site](http://github.com/radar/ryanbigg.com) that you could use as an example if you're stuck. The documentation contains pretty good examples as well.

But to get you started: Jekyll doesn't really have any database backing to it. You must create the directory structure--as outlined in the [Usage guide](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Usage)--yourself.

For generating new posts, I have a script called `new.rb` in my repository. Simply because I can't be bothered remembering what the Wordpress ID was for the previous post (I imported from Wordpress).

Once you've got a post written, install the `jekyll` gem:

```
gem install jekyll
```

Then run `jekyll --server`. This will parse the post into beautiful HTML which you can view at http://localhost:4000. Once you're satisfied with it, put it online somewhere with Apache or Nginx serving it as it would any other static HTML site.

---

Finally, if you're ever looking for an alternative, I've heard good things about [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll is not a Rails project.  There is no db:create Rake task.

I'd suggest taking a look @ the [documentation](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki) to figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll is not a rails app, however...

I would always start with the project's Gemfile (if they are using bundler), if the developer has specified versions for the gems, this should give you a good look at the specific version requirements.